# How to have views with depth in Xcode view hierarchy?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm currently attempting to reproduce the behaviour of `UIPickerView`, writing it myself from scratch.

There's one aspect of it that I can't reproduce, which is this "view" with depth that appears at Xcode's Debug View Hierarchy tab (picture below). I quoted the view word because I don't know if it is a `UIView`. It is not selectable in the Debug View Hierarchy tab, but I can hover the cursor over it and it gets a purple highlight color, as in the picture.

My guess was that it is some sort of `CALayer`, so I tried multiple different combinations of the following aspects:

- `CATransformLayer`
- `m34` value of `CATransform3D`
- Rotation/Translation transforms
- `CALayer`'s `zPosition`

However, all drawing done using those modifications gets projected into 2 dimensions, as expected.

Looking into the hierarchy tree, it seems that this 3D box is the child of a `UIPickerTableView`. The cells inside it are of the type `UIPickerTableViewTitledCell`. Both types seem to be internal. I did not try using a plain table or collection view yet, because I'm thinking that plain `CALayer` customization should be able to do the job.

Is there any way to reproduce it?

[image: "view" with depth]

This picture is generated by adding a `UIPickerView` on top of a plain `UIViewController`'s `view`, running the project on a simulator and then clicking on the Debug View Herarchy button on Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is just a built-in visualization feature of XCode especially for `UIPickerView` and its subclasses (or maybe for some other similar views). If you focus deeper this cubes will disappear and you'll see these transformed labels layers (this works in XCode 11 not so well though with focusing).

Another example, in Reveal (visualization tool for AppCode) you'll see views frames (blue frames) and their transformed layers (filled frames) without this 3D visualization and the whole picker view looks flat

[image]

Comment: So I guess my own views will always suffer orthographic projection in the debugger, but UIKit built-ins sometimes won't? Thanks for the response!

Comment: @LucasBarbosa I think yes unless you inherit from those "projection-enabled" views, for instance in my `UIPickerView` subclass this trick works